# Don't know how to generate the query I need using Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I've got an Entity Framework 4 model.  There's 2 tables in that model, Subscribers and Versions:

```
CREATE TABLE tracking."Subscribers"
(
    "SubscriberId"       UUID               NOT NULL,
    "RemoteAddress"      VARCHAR(80)        NOT NULL,
    "Priority"           INTEGER            NOT NULL DEFAULT 100,
    "DataTypeId"         INTEGER            NOT NULL REFERENCES tracking."DataTypes" ( "DataTypeId" ),
    "Condition"          VARCHAR(8000),
    "Version"            BIGINT             NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "LastConnected"      TIMESTAMPTZ        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Subscribers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("SubscriberId", "DataTypeId")
);


CREATE TABLE tracking."Versions"
(
    "ObjectId"           UUID               NOT NULL,
    "Source"             UUID                   NULL,
    "From"               BIGINT             NOT NULL,
    "To"                 BIGINT                 NULL,
    "DataTypeId"         INTEGER            NOT NULL REFERENCES tracking."DataTypes" ( "DataTypeId" ),
    CONSTRAINT "Versions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ObjectId", "DataTypeId")
);
```

Yes, there is a third table, DataTypes, but it's a lookup table & isn't important.

Also, you need to know that the values stored in the From & To columns in the Versions table represent version numbers.  If the To column is not null, it means that the particular item represented by ObjectId has been deleted from the database.

In my C# code, I need to build a query.  There is a Dictionary which contains one entry for each combination of data type ID & version number.  I need to build a series of tests spearated by ORs, not ANDs.

Normally, to build the condition as a string for use in a DbCommand, I'd use code like this:

```
bool isFirst = true;
string query = "...";

foreach ( KeyValuePair<int, long> version in versionsLastSent ) {
    if ( ! isFirst ) {
        query += " OR ";
    }

    query += "....";
    isFirst = false;
}
```

However, I don't know how to get that OR into the query using entity framework.  I know that my query will be a generic IQueryable object and that I add conditions to it using

```
query = query.Where( a => ... );
```

But these are normally separated by ANDs.  I need ORs.

How do I do this?

Tony

Edit:

I forgot to mention that the query needs to look like this when done:

SELECT * 
FROM Versions 
JOIN Subscribers . . .
WHERE <Some Condition> AND ( VersionCondition1 OR VersionCondition2 OR . . . )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be without `OR`, because you can get the exact same results using `Union`:

```
IQueryable originalQuery = ...;
IQueryable query = null;

foreach ( KeyValuePair<int, long> version in versionsLastSent ) {
    IQueryable queryPart = originalQuery.Where(...);
    if (query == null)
        query = queryPart;
    else
        query = query.Union(queryPart);
}
```

Comment: This looks promising!  I'll give this a shot & see if it works.

Comment: Is that query.Whwere call in the first line in the foreach supposed to be originalQuery.Where?

Comment: @TonyVitabile Yes, thanks for catching that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: My problem right now is I don't know how to do the AND part (see my edit to the original question).  I've broken this up as "baseQuery = from version in . . ."; I have "versionQuery = null; foreach ( ... ) { queryPart = baseQuery.Where( version => ...); if ( versionQuery == null ) versionQuery = queryPart; else versionQuery = versionQuery.Union( queryPart);}  But now I need to combine the versionQuery with the original baseQuery.

Comment: @TonyVitabile You can move that SomeCondition into the originalQuery, which would change your `SELECT * FROM table WHERE a AND (b OR c)` into `SELECT * FROM table WHERE a AND b UNION SELECT * FROM table WHERE a AND c`, again with the same results.

Comment: @TonyVitabile Alternatively, you can add the SomeCondition at the very end: `foreach (...) { ... } if (query != null) query = query.Where(SomeCondition);`

Comment: I was under deadline pressure and I backed this out as I was having trouble with it.  It's a known bug in the release we just generated, but I am going to give adding the SomeCondition at the end a try.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PredicateBuilder.

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Basically you'd do something like this... (rough psuedo-code)

```
var predicate = new PredicateBuilder.False<YourType>();

if(someCondition)
{
   predicate = predicate.Or(x=>x == newCondition);
}

query = context.where(predicate);
```

It's important to start with .False() if you're using OR to construct your query. This will give you a base evaluation to false that you can build on.